# What are labels and indices in Neo4j?

Tags: ruby, neo4j

I am using [neo4j-core gem](https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j-core) ([Neo4j::Node API](http://rdoc.info/github/andreasronge/neo4j-core/Neo4j/Node)). It is the only MRI-compatible Ruby binding of neo4j that I could find, and hence is valuable, but its documentation is a crap (it has missing links, lots of typographical errors, and is difficult to comprehend). In the **Label and Index Support** section of the first link, it says:

- Create a node with an [sic] label `person` and one property

  ```
  Neo4j::Node.create({name: 'kalle'}, :person)
  ```
- Add index on a label

  ```
  person = Label.create(:person)
  person.create_index(:name)
  ```
- drop index

  ```
  person.drop_index(:name)
  ```

(whose second code line I believe is a typographical error of the following)

```
person = Node4j::Label.create(:person)
```

- What is a label, is it the name of a database table, or is it an attribute peculiar to a node?
- If it is the name of a node, I don't under the fact that (according to the API in the second link) the method `Neo4j::Node.create`  and `Neo4j::Node#add_label` can take multiple arguments for the label. What does it mean to have multiple labels on a node?
- Furthermore, If I repeat the `create` command with the same label argument, it creates a different node object each time. What does it mean to have multiple nodes with the same name? Isn't a label something to identify a node?
- What is index? How are labels and indices different?

Comment: The version you're working with is an alpha release of version 3.0, so a lot of features aren't implemented and the documentation needs a major overhaul. If you want to use Neo4j with Ruby MRI, you might want to consider Neography (https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography) until Neo4j.rb 3.0 is finalized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Labels are a way of grouping nodes. You can give the label to many nodes or just one node. Think of it as a collection of nodes that are grouped together. They allow you to assign indexes and other constraints.

An index allows quick lookup of nodes or edges without having to traverse the entire graph to find them. Think of it as a table of direct pointers to the particular nodes/edges indexed.

Comment: You mean index is the whole table, or is it a key within a table? Your explanation on label made it clear, but I still don't get the difference between label and index. It seems that an index can be assigned to a label, which can be assigned to multiple nodes. Then, does it mean that an index is not something to uniquely identify a node?

Comment: @sawa An index is something like a "table" of keys to find nodes and relationships. But you don't get access to the "table." I'm not sure if it's a table internally, but it is exactly like an address for the node. If you index a certain node or group of nodes, and there are 10,000,000 nodes in your database, then query for one indexed node, Neo4j will consult the lookup table and return just that node quickly without traversing the graph.

Comment: How is that different from labeling those nodes, and selecting the nodes with that label? Does a label lack that functionality? If so, I don't get what label is for.

Comment: @sawa: it's a graph. Think of the label as the table in a DB. Nodes as DB rows, which can belong to one or more labels/tables, or no label/table at all for that matter. And indexes as DB indexes.

Comment: @sawa Labels are not indexed, but you need labels to index nodes. That's how they're different. Labels are purely groups and don't speed up access necessarily. Indexes are pointers to specific nodes and speed up direct access to those nodes considerably.

Comment: @sawa Think of it this way. Even if you add labels to nodes and query for those labels, the database may have to search all over the graph to find labeled nodes. If you index them, they can be accessed directly.

Comment: @Denis That slightly confuses the issue, I think, because adding labels means you still have to traverse the graph to find labeled nodes whereas indexing means you don't have to traverse the graph. The table metaphor only goes so far. I guess it would be something like jumping to the exact record you need in a big table without looking at any other record.

Answer (score 2):

As I read what you pasted from the docs (and without, admittedly, knowing the slightest thing about neo4j):

- It's a graph database, where every piece of data is a *node* with a certain amount of properties.
- Each node can have a *label* (or more, presumably?). Think of it as a type -- or perhaps more appropriately, in Ruby parlance, a Module.
- It's a database, so nodes can be part of an *index* for quicker access. So can subsets of nodes, and therefor nodes with a certain label.

Put another way: Think of the label as the table in a DB. Nodes as DB rows, which can belong to one or more labels/tables, or no label/table at all for that matter. And indexes as DB indexes on sets of rows.